# How do you reject a Binary on the Amazon App Store?

Tags: binaryfiles, submission, amazon-appstore

I just submitted a binary for an update to an existing app on the amazon app store and realized there was a mistake in it. I went to reject it but I see no way to do it once I've hit submit. Any ideas on how I can reject the Bianry of the app update and add a new one?

Thanks,

Nick

Comment: Any luck.... did you sorted it out.

Answer (score 1):

to have an in-process app put back into a state where you can submit a new version simply use the Contact Us form in the developer portal and they can do that for you pretty quickly